# Storing data as a blob vs columns in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I have a lot of row data for events. These events share some common identifiers, but also have data unique to the event.

Since Cassandra does not allow where clauses over fields that are not indexed, is there any advantage to making a row for each of these keys or would it be easier to just store the json data in a blob?

Example

table has a key on (event_type, timestamp) partitioned by event_type

event_type `click` might have `ts:12345 page_uri: "ABC1234" user_id: "1235567" click_location: "1234,564"`
event_type `keyboard_input` might have `ts:1245 page_uri: "ABC345" words_entered: "foobar"`

Is there any advantage of storing this as a table with rows:

`event_type, ts, page_uri, user_id, click_location, words_entered`

vs a table

`event_type, ts, blob`

where blob is a json encoded map of the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few immediate advantages to storing the data in columns come to mind:

1. You can add a new index at a later date if you determine you suddenly need to query by another field.
2. You can update specific fields only without updating the entire row.  With a blob you need to read and update the entire blob.  Concurrent updates to different fields could be wiped out in the blob case as a result.
3. You can write less data with each update due to #2 above.
4. You can read less data with each select if you do not need all of the columns
5. #3 and #4 above may lead to a performance benefit.